# How to deploy a JRuby Resque process as a war file?

Tags: tomcat, delayed-job, resque, jrubyonrails, warbler

I have a JRuby/Rails application which is deployed as a WAR file and run in the Tomcat application server. I would like to use either delayed_job or Resque as a tool to do long-running jobs which schlep through the database through the same ActiveRecord subclasses use by my Rails application. And I want it to run in a different process or thread so as not to make my web-facing side of the application seem slow.

The instructions to include and use delayed_job or Resque are pretty clear. For example, once I have done all of the jiggery-pokery to use Resque, I simply have to do:

```
QUEUE=* jruby -J-cp /path/to/library -S rake environment resque:work
```

But this only works from the command line. How do I get it so that my Resque process(es) can run by deploying a WAR file to Tomcat? If so, is it the same WAR file with a different configuration or a different WAR file? If it is a different WAR file, how do I generate it?  Do I need a second Tomcat for the Resque/DJ process? Is there a way to put the Resque/DJ process into its own JRuby/JVM thread? Is there any configuration jiggery-pokery I must do to get this going?

Answer (score 0):

JRuby does recognize shell commands whose `ARGV[0] =~ /ruby$/` and run them in-process, so you could use this to your advantage. Assuming you include your `Rakefile` in your war file, you could start a thread and launch Resque in it with a similar command from an application initializer. If you're using Bundler, it will already have the environment set up and it should be passed to the in-process child JRuby.

Comment: I assume that this means in config/initializers/resque.rb I would write something like: require 'java'; Thread.new do XXXXXX end.  What is XXXXXX so that I can start the JRuby Thread with the Resque task?

Comment: I eventually got this working by writing a script which starts the Resque process after the WAR file has been exploded on the deployment server. i.e. No Tomcat, just JRuby. Perhaps my understanding of Tomcat is flawed. Does Tomcat limit you to one process? If so, do I have to deploy Resque in a different Tomcat? If not, how do I start Resque without depending on the web app exploding the WAR file?